Azure APIM: Don't Return Error If Token Validation Fails
I'm using the validate-jwt reference for validating my tokens which works perfectly fine.
<validate-jwt token-value="@((string)context.Variables["access_token"])"
          failed-validation-httpcode="401"
          failed-validation-error-message="Access token is invalid"
          output-token-variable-name="jwt-token">
    <openid-config url="{{well-known-url}}" />
</validate-jwt>

What I couldn't figure out: how do I not return an error in my policy if the validation fails?
I want to continue in my policy in another path (e.g. by setting a variable to false that I can then branch at with <choose>).
Is that even possible?

In validation fail, do you want to return a custom response? Also share the policy you have tried to achieve this @tpschmidt

You can handle the validation failed error by using the given policy wherein I am explicitly setting the status and a custom message.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="isTokenValid" value="false" />
        <set-variable name="access_token" value="*******" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@((string)context.Variables["access_token"] != null)">
                <validate-jwt token-value="@((string)context.Variables["access_token"])" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Access token is invalid" output-token-variable-name="jwt-token">
                    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                </validate-jwt>
                <set-variable name="isTokenValid" value="true" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-variable name="isTokenValid" value="false" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables["isTokenValid"] == "true")">
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <!-- Do something else if the token validation failed -->
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="200" reason="Invalid Token" />
                    <set-body>Proceed further</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </on-error>
</policies>





I also thought about this, but it doesn't solve my actual problem: if the access token is either invalid or expired, I don't want to return a response but continue with the flow.

@tpschmidt What do you mean by continue with the flow? Do you have any other policies? At least you need to return the status code or else it will give you 401 error

I just don't want to return a response at that step on a failure - as if the whole validate-jwt would be optional. Either it successfully validates and writes the output variable or it doesn't.

@tpschmidt in that case only return the status code, don't add set-body
